# Keep on summing corresponding cell and compare with first column for summing up first column based on comparision in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

Consider the following data setup:

```
_A_  _B_  _C_
 1    1
 2    1    1
 3    3
```

Such that a formula would return the following results for columns B and C respectively:

```
_A_  _B_  _C_
      4    2
```

Now I want to sum column A if A-(B+C) is equal to 0.

so for above example sum would be 1+3 = 4 on column B, since row 1 and 3 satisfy 1-1=0 first row, 3-3=0 third row. so A value on 1st and 2nd row is 1+3=4. Row 2nd doesn't satisfy 2-1=1 not 0  so ignore.

on column C, B+C in second row 2-(1+1) = 0 ,So it would be sum 2 in that column C, ignoring first and third row since it already has been counted on column B.

columns continue like D E....

So sum up from B to current column..so if i am in column B it will sum up till B.If in C B+C....If in D B+C+D etc and then compare with column A

Comment: Can you reword your explanation of the calculated fields? :)

Comment: can you check now if you can understand?

Comment: Explanation is not clear and inconsistent i.e 
It says _SUMPRODUCT or SUMIF can used in formula_ then goes like: 
_Such that a formula would return the following results for columns B and C respectively:_ but it does not show the formula it’s referring to.  
It also says _Now I want to sum column A if A-(B+C) is equal to 0._
but then: _Row 2nd doesn't satisfy 2-1=1 not 0 so ignore._ actually all rows in sample data comply with the condition (A-B-C)=0, for row two is (2-1-1)=0.

Answer (score 0):

Insufficient rep to comment, this is at least a partial answer and perhaps full.

I think you're looking for this to happen in some lower row in B:

=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A3=B1:B3),A1:A3)

And this in C:

=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A3-(B1:B3+C1:C3)=0),A1:A3)

Although as EEM points out all the sample rows satisfy this condition so you get "6" instead of "2"